# Calculating sentence length and average words per sentence? | Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first Javascript project. I have to count the words, spaces, sentences, and average words per sentence. I have already done the first two steps to the code and have made it so it calculates the words and spaces. I'm not really sure how to average the words per sentence or the amount of sentences.

For words per sentence I'm thinking I should somehow use the value of the word count I already have in the function and divide it by its sum, but I'm not really sure how to set that up. For the sentence one, I am kind of clueless on how to do it. I don't know if I could maybe scan the input for periods/question marks/exclamation points? I've looked it up and can't find anything specific enough that I'm looking for. Any pointers?? Here's the code:
HTML

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="">
<textarea name="inpString" cols="49" rows="4"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" name="Count" value="Calculate" onClick="countNoOfWords();" />  
<input name="noofwords" type="text" value="" size="6" />
<input name="noofspaces" type="text" value="" size="6" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function countNoOfWords() {

 document.myform.noofwords.value = document.myform.inpString.value.split(' ').length + " words";
 document.myform.noofspaces.value = document.myform.inpString.value.split(" ").length - 1 + " spaces";

}
```

Thanks so much, I really appreciate it. Let me know if there are any questions.

I'm thinking now I could use an if statement to find periods/question marks/exclamation points and then return that value for finding the number of sentences. I don't really know though.

Comment: Hi Grim.The average you are expecting,is it number of words/no of sentences??

Comment: @grim I tried your code by creating a sample page in notepad and it seems to be working as you described it should. I see the form and when I type words into it separated by spaces, it gives the right word count and spaces.

Comment: @SunilHari I am looking for the average number of words in a sentence. So somehow I'd have to set it up to recognize if something is a sentence first, but I'm really having trouble figuring that out!

Comment: @nocturns2 Yes, the code I currently have works. I am asking for tips on how to find the average amount of words in a sentence as well as how many sentences are present in the input. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Comment: What are the downvotes about? is my question unclear? ):

Comment: @grim I think Christian Santos is suggesting what I would have.

Comment: I believe that this question is a valid post. Clear explanation, working code sample, and legitimate question (how to get the average number of words in a sentence) +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting the number of sentences, take a look at [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in JavaScript, which will allow you to split the text into an array of sentences:

```
function getNoOfSentences() {
    var val = document.myform.inpString.value;
    var sentences = val.split(/[\.!?]+/); // split on punctuation
    return sentences.length - 1; // subtract 1 to account for last sentence
}
```

Once you have the sentences, you can calculate average number of words per sentence by taking your total number of words divided by the number of sentences:

```
var averageWords = totalWords / numSentences;
```

Comment: this helped a lot, thanks! and thank you for the resource as well (: